# Node.js: Pipe stream with parsed data to another stream

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I have a `Readable` that pipes into a `WritableStream` (https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2?tab=readme-ov-file#usage-with-streams) from one library, which provides a SAX interface for parsing data. I want to pipe SAX stream into a new stream that takes parsed data and performs buffered inserts into a database (using async await).

Objective is following:

1. Get file stream from S3
2. Parse with Writable Stream from htmlparser2
3. During parsing push chunks of data to Kafka

Here's what I managed to do without using pipes:

```
const content: Readable = getFileFromS3()

const chunkSize: number = 50
const handler = async (data) => ...

const writableKafkaStream = new KafkaWritableStream(chunksSize, handler)

const currentParsingObject = {}

const parser = new SaxWritableStream(
    {
        onopentag(name, attributes) {
            // ... construct data based on opened tag
            currentParsingObject.someProp = name
        },

        ontext(text) {
            // ... construct data based on text
            currentParsingObject.text = text
        },

        onclosetag(tagname) {
            // ... finish constructing data and write to a stream
            currentParsingObject.someProp2 = tagname

            // sending data to another stream
            writableKafkaStream.write(currentParsingObject)
        },
    },
    { xmlMode: true },
)

return new Promise(resolve => {
    content.pipe(parser).on('finish', () => {
        writableKafkaStream.end()
        resolve(count)
    })
})
```

But it looks like it overflows `writableKafkaStream` and does not pause the original stream while running writes in `writableKafkaStream`.

I am searching for a method to pipe the `writableKafkaStream`. As the `SaxWritableStream` solely triggers event callbacks (ontext, ontag and etc), I'm unsure of how to direct parsed data to another stream through piping.

EDIT:

I have added some pauses to the original stream when the `write` returns false:

```
onclosetag(tagname) {
    if (shouldAddToWritableKafkaStream) {
        if (!writableKafkaStream.write(data)) {
            content.pause()
            writableKafkaStream.once('drain', () => {
                content.resume()
            })
        }
        count += 1
    }
},
```

It seems to work (memory not consuming too much) but it shows lots of warnings:

```
(node:26490) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [KafkaTransporterTransformStream]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

Comment: What is `SaxWritableStream`? Does it await the result of the asynchronous `onclosetag` handler before accepting more input?

Comment: Added some details in the question. Surely it does not await - just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You use the throttling mechanism "if `write` returns false then `pause` and `resume` on `drain`". But this throttles only the chunks being written to the SAX `parser`, and even one chunk can be so big that it leads to many `writableKafkaStream.write` operations, which may still overflow Kafka. This also explains the warnings about too many `drain` handlers that you observe.

I propose a different throttling mechanism which ensures that a write operation to Kafka finishes before the next one starts. This requires an asynchronous `writeToKafka` function which awaits the callback from the `writableKafkaStream.write` operation (assuming this callback happens only after Kafka has received the data):

```
function writeToKafka(currentParsingObject) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    writableKafkaStream.write(currentParsingObject, function(err) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

Using this function, the synchronous `onclosetag` handler can maintain a `queue` of promises which makes the writing to Kafka asynchronous.

To also pause the original stream, pipe your `content` into a `Writable` stream that passes it on to the SAX `parser` only after the previous `queue` has completed:

```js
var queue = Promise.resolve();
const parser = new SaxWritableStream({
  ...
  onclosetag(tagname) {
    // ... finish constructing data and write to a stream
    currentParsingObject.someProp2 = tagname
    // sending data to another stream
    queue = queue.then(
      writeToKafka.bind(undefined, currentParsingObject)
    );
  }
  ...
});
content.pipe(new stream.Writable({
  write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    queue.then(function() {
      queue = Promise.resolve();
      parser.write(chunk);
      callback();
    });
  },
  finish(callback) {
    queue.then(function() {
      parser.end();
      callback();
    });
  }
}));
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, didn't think about this ordering! Thanks for idea with using promises queue. However, I've solved my problem by involving generators and for-await-of operator: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/6SVytnFE). Do you think it is an equal solution or even more efficient because it does not create an additional stream?

Comment: I don't think I can judge which solution is more efficient.